# How to sort array by date name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort my array by date name.
This is an example from my array,

```
let data = [
  {
    day: "Saturday"
    isOpen: false
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  },
  {
    day: "Sunday"
    isOpen: false
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  },
  {
    day: "Friday"
    isOpen: false
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  }
]
```

Then I want my array will be like this

```
let data = [
  {
    day: "Friday"
    isOpen: false
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  },
  {
    day: "Saturday"
    isOpen: false
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  },
  {
    day: "Sunday"
    isOpen: false
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  }
]
```

I have read about sorting function in javascript, but I still cant find how to sort by date name.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: What is "date name"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array for maintaining the order of the days. Then iterate this array & use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the matched day from `data` array. Array filter will return an array, so using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the content & pushing it to the `sorted` array.

```js
const dateOrder = ['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
let data = [{
    day: "Saturday",
    isOpen: false,
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  },
  {
    day: "Sunday",
    isOpen: false,
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  },
  {
    day: "Friday",
    isOpen: false,
    description: "07:00 - 18:00 WIB"
  }
];
let sorted = [];
dateOrder.forEach((item) => {
  sorted.push(...data.filter(elem => elem.day === item));
  
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: I know this way is better than `.sort`, but if you could share a reference link for readers, it'll be great

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.day>b.day)
```

(MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

// Edit
How abt this?

```
let weekDays = { Mon: 0, Tue: 1, Wed: 2, Thu: 3, Fri: 4, Sat: 5, Sun: 6, }
data.sort((a, b) => weekDays[a.day.slice(0, 3)] > weekDays[b.day.slice(0, 3)])
```

Comment: @Rajesh edited :)

Comment: Minor suggestion: Since you control object, it would be better to keep keys as entire day's name instead of nick. That would enable you to skip `day.slice(...)`.

Comment: @Rajesh It's up to you how you write it ^-^